# CKEditor display cke_iframe instead of youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, ckeditor

I use CKEditor and YouTube plugin, it works when I was creating and display outside the editor.

But when I want to edit the same post which I saved before, it won't display the iframe, instead, it displays this code.

```
<img class="cke_iframe" data-cke-realelement="%3Ciframe%20allowfullscreen%3D%22%22%20class%3D%22embed_video%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2FkAkVMA3KvI8%3Frel%3D0%26amp%3Bstart%3Dundefined%26amp%3Bstart%3Dundefined%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E" data-cke-real-node-type="1" alt="IFrame" title="IFrame" align="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-cke-real-element-type="iframe" data-cke-resizable="true">
```

[image]

But What I save is like

```
<p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zjzT_BCYgnU?rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;modestbranding=1" class="embed_video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p><p><br></p>
```

After I destory the instances of CKEditor by following code, it will remain the original situation.

```
_.forOwn(CKEDITOR.instances, function(value, key) {
  CKEDITOR.instances[key].destroy();
});
```

[image]

So, how do I display the original ifram without destory the CKEditor instance?

Comment: the ifram you use to display youtube url is original ifram plugin? I was use http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube this youtube plugin to show out youtube embed

Comment: Yeah, I use the same plugin. The question is that it will become a picture when I want to edit what it had saved.

Comment: have you managed to solve this?